# angularjs Array not regnized by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api

I'm writing an API on NodeJS (server part) and AngularJS (view part) which asks another API (NodeJS too) to get an object containing stuff including  an array of pictures. I'm interested by the pictures in this array.

I wrote a for loop to get names of all pictures contained in my array of pictures in my object:

```
for(j=0; j<reference.pictures.length; j++){
   self.url ="http://localhost:3000/api/pictures/"+reference.pictures[j].picture;
   self.urlArray = urlArray.push(self.url);
 }
 console.log(urlArray);
```

And I wrote for my view an ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="url in urlArray">
  <img ng-src="{{url}}"  width="150px"/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

My problem ? I can see my urls contained in my array of urls in log when I console.log BUT I can't see 'em in my view with my ng-repeat. I guess my ng-repeat isn't perfect but still don't know why
Any ideas ?

To understand, I want to show all my pictures contained in my array so FIRST I did that:

controller:

```
    self.url = "http://localhost:3000/api/pictures/"+reference.pictures[j].picture;
```

view:

```
<div ng-repeat="picture in reference.pictures">
  <img ng-src="{{url}}"  width="150px"/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

and in result I have the good number of pictures, BUT the URL used to get pictures is the last one which is assigned exiting the loop, so all my pictures are the same (the last one), this is why I get the idea to make an array with all my different URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lack to construct `urlArray` as an array of **object literals**, i.e :

```js
[
  { url: 'someUrl' }, 
  { url: 'anotherUrl' },
  ...
]
```

So do this instead :

```js
self.urlArray = [];
for(j=0; j<reference.pictures.length; j++) {
  self.urlArray.push({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/pictures/"+reference.pictures[j].picture
  })
}
```

...

```html
<div ng-repeat="url in urlArray">
  <img ng-src="{{ url.url }}" width="150px">
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're referring to `$scope` using `self`. If that's the case, the main problem with your code is this assignment:

```
self.urlArray = urlArray.push(self.url);
```

`Array#push` returns the length of the updated array, so `self.urlArray` will always contain an integer. And you cannot loop over an integer using `ng-repeat` in AngularJS. To solve the issue, just remove the assignment:

```
urlArray.push(self.url);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying

Yes u'r right self =$scope
But when I remove the assignment, I still don't have my view updated with my pictures, this is why I believed that my ng-repeat isn't correct
But thx, now I know why I always had an integer when I console.log urlArray ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are some nuances with prototypical inheritance in Angular - check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs/14049482#14049482) for a more in-depth explanation.

Basically, your `ng-repeat` can't access the `urlArray` that you want because a new variable is created in `childScope` that *overshadows* the same variable in `parentScope`. If you were to instead make `urlArray` a property of an object, that should fix your issue.